# Find the area of the sector

Tags: trigonometry

I am given radius= $10$ and $\theta=0.5$ rad. To find the area of a sector is $A=\frac{1}{2}r^2\theta$. But when i compute it, i get 25. However, the book has 50 as an answer. I don't understand what i did wrong. Can someone help me out?

Comment: This is for a circle?

Comment: This is for a circle. I am getting the formula from the book, for the area of a circular sector.

Comment: For $0\le \theta\le 2\pi$, the area of a circular sector requires $r^2\theta\over 2$, just as you've written, and you have calculated correctly as near as I can tell.

Comment: Then your textbook is wrong, explained below by amWhy.

Comment: Yes, the formula is correct: we essentially find the area of $\dfrac \theta{2\pi}^{\text{th}}$ of the area of a circle $\pi r^2$

Answer (score 4):

What you need is $$A =\left(\dfrac \theta{2\pi}\right)\cdot (\pi r^2 ) = \dfrac{r^2 \theta}{2}$$ for $\theta$ measured in radians, so the formula is correct. You are correct that with $\theta = 0.5$, the resultant area is $25$.

Comment: @abiessu We have the factor $\dfrac \theta{2\pi}$ that computes the fraction of a full rotation) and the factor $\pi r^2$ (area of the entire circle). the $\pi$ cancel out.

Comment: No, abiessu: I just moved the factors around. Check the original post, they were all there, and correct. I changed it only to make the logic more transparent: $$A = \frac{\pi r^2 \theta}{2 \pi}$$

Comment: Weird, I must be going blind, but I was certain that your formula read $A=\dfrac {\theta r^2}{2\pi}$ and didn't have any mention that the OPs formula was correct.  No worries though.